# How to write scripts in VS code using playwright + cucumber with typescript and POM concept

Tags: typescript, cucumber, pom.xml

I am currently learning Playwright for web application automation scripting.
The requirement is to use Playwright with Cucumber and Page Object Model using Typescript

Could you please provide any example which will show end to end flow that how can I create Project folder structure and write scripts in VS code using playwright + cucumber with typescript and POM concept?

I am trying below things but facing challenges while integration:

1. To integrate Feature files with Step definition files
2. And to use POM concept in Step Definition

I am expecting to get:

1. Integration of Feature files with step definition files properly
2. Use of POM in Step definition to reuse and maintain the code
3. How to use and maintain Test-data file

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Feature File

```
Scenario Outline: User Login
Given: I can login as user "<userName>" with password "<password>"
Examples: 
|userName|password|
|testUser|testing|
// you can add multiple test data here
```

Step definition
// **You can integrate feature file with step defination file like this**

```
import {Login} from '../page-objects/login-page'
const login =new Login()
Given('I can login as user {string} with password {string}',async (userName,password)=>{
await login.Login(userName,password) // and like this you can use POM concept in step defination
})
```

Page-Object File

```
export class Login {
async login(){
    await page.locator("[id='userName']").fill(userName)
    await page.locator("[id='password']").fill(password)
    await page.locator("[id='loginBtn']").click()
}
```

Summary: We are passing test data from feature file into step definition and then passing that data further into page-object (POM) which will be filled in userName and password fields.

Here is what your structure will look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1nJr.png)